# Phone 8.1 EventTraiggerBehavior pass parameter to converter

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have the following XAML markup in my Phone 8.1 universal app

```
<Grid x:Name="AuthProviders" >
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction 
                Command="{Binding LoginCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                InputConverter="{StaticResource GridItemSelConverter}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="AuthenticationProviders"  ItemsSource="{Binding AuthenticationProviders}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>                        
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource LoginButtonStyle}">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource LoginConverter}}"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Now in the GridItemSelConverter I need to include the following code

```
return ((value as TappedRoutedEventArgs).OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyActualDataModel
```

I dont like this since I need to get the original source and there is a lot of conversion, is there any easier way to obtain the underlying data model instead of going this way?